# Can parsley.js work with knockout.js?

Tags: validation, knockout.js, parsley.js

I just learned about parsley.js and I'm trying to add it's validation capabilities to my project that is already wired up with knockout.js bindings.  Here is the markup:

```
<form id="form-add-gift" data-bind="submit: addGift" data-validate="parsley">
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Gift</th><th>Description</th><th>Url</th><th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td><input id="txtName" name="txtName" type="text" data-required="true" data-bind="value: newGift().name" /></td>
                <td><input id="txtDescription" name="txtDescription" type="text" data-bind="value: newGift().description" /></td>
                <td><input id="txtUrl" name="txtUrl" type="text" data-type="url" data-bind="value: newGift().url" /></td>
                <td><button id="btnAdd" name="btnAdd" class="btn" type="submit" data-bind="disable: newGift().name.length > 0">Add gift</button></td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: gifts">
            <tr>
                <td id="tdName" data-bind="text: name"></td>
                <td id="tdDescription" data-bind="text: description"></td>
                <td id="tdUrl" data-bind="text: url"></td>
                <td><a id="btnRemove" class="btn btn-danger" href="#" data-bind="disabled: $parent.isClaimed, click: $parent.removeGift">Remove</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

When I click the "Add gift" button, my knockout.js addGift() function fires and the parsley.js validation occurs afterward.  Obviously this is incorrect.  Is there any way to get parsley.js to play nice with the knockout.js bindings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think [parsley.js](http://parsleyjs.org/documentation.html) meant to work directly with [KnockoutJs](http://knockoutjs.com/), but this can't stop you from using them both *nicely*.

Quick look through the **[Documentation](http://parsleyjs.org/documentation.html) -> Javascript - > Form** you can use this method:

```
$('#form').parsley('isValid');
```

> Useful if you want to integrate the form validation process inside
>   custom functions, without triggering error messages.

**UPDATE**

you can try this too:

```
$( '#form' ).parsley( 'validate' );
```

> Useful if you want to integrate the form validation process inside
>   custom functions.

Comment: Thanks!  Not sure how I missed that in the documentation.  Looks like I just need to wrap my knockout.js function code in a `if ($('#form-add-gift').parsley('isValid')) { ... }` block.

Comment: With the current version of parsley.js, one would write `$('#form').parsley().isValid()` - see http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#usage-form